# Fill drop down list via mysql select query

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, select

I have this php script that's supposed to fill a drop down list; I actually embedded it into the `<select>` element but it didn't work.
Here's my script to clearly explain my problem :

```
<select name="cats">
   <?php
   require_once("connection.php");
   $rs = mysql_query("select cat_name from category");
   $count = 0;
   while($array = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo "<option>".$array[$count]."</option>";
   }
   mysql_close($con);
   ?>
 
  </select>
```

Can help me to define the error and if this is the wrong way to do it?
What is the better approach?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [**prepared statements**](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I also see that you prepare a $count variable. If you use it as an unique index don't forget to increment it $count++; in the while loop

Comment: thx i found that i already missed the increment :$

Comment: Please don't put code like this in the view. Familiarize yourself with a php framework or at least a template library.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
   echo "<option>".$array[$count]."</option>";
}
```

to

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    echo "<option value='".$array["cat_id"]."'>".$array["cat_name"]."</option>";
}
```

where `cat_id` is id of your category table

Answer (score 0):

In general terms this is the right way to do it. I assume the problem is here:

```
echo "<option>".$array[$count]."</option>";
```

Your `$count` is necessarily 0, so you will always be outputting `$array[0]`, which is the first field that's being selected (usually some kind of ID, but it depends on the table structure). This may or may not be the right field in the table.

What I recommend is first to specify the exact fields you're selecting. For example:

```
select `id`, `text` from `category`
```

And then use the associative array `$array` to get what you want, for example: `$array['id']`

Answer (score 0):

i think there is not any issues with your code , check your database connection again and try.because i try your code in my localhost and fetch cat_name in dropdown list.